# How to determine if custom post type showing on archive templates

Tags: custom-post-types, breadcrumb

Is there any way to determine if a particular custom post type will be displayed on default archive pages or search results?

e.g.
Given a post type named (badly) **books**, is there a way to tell **via code** any of the following:

- If books show up on date archives
- If books show up in search results
- If books show up in author archives

I know how to make custom post types show up in these, but I've been doing a bit of digging and can see no clean way to determine if a particular custom post type will show up in any of the above or not.

The main reason I'm looking for this is that I'm creating custom breadcrumb bars for a theme... and it would be nice to be able to show an authors breadcrumb bar if the custom post being viewed supports author functionality **and** shows up in the author archive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [get the post type object](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_type_object/) and check its properties. For example:

```
$post_type = get_post_type_object( 'books' );
if( $post_type->exclude_from_search ) {
    // The post type is not included in search results
}
if( $post_type->has_archive ) {
    // The post type has archive
}
```

As far I know, custom post types are not included in dates archives nor author archives if you don't code for it (using [`pre_get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) for example). I mean, those options are not available while registering a post type. So, there is no way to check it from post type object.

Comment: Thanks! I searched all over hoping to find something, but finally decided to ask as I was turning up nothing in the source.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on the front, on template you can use the [`is_post_type_archive( $post_types )`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_post_type_archive) conditional tag function. `$post_types` can be a `string` or an `array` of posts types to check against.

Comment: I'm not looking to see whether I am on a post type archive or not, but whether to see if the currently viewed post type is displayed on one of the builtin archive pages. Thanks though.